# Reducing a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Consider the following sentence:

- [*We have to make*] *one more effort, and* [*then*] *we will rest!*

Can the first and second clauses be reduced by removing what is in brackets?

The result could be:

*a)*    *One more effort, and we will rest!*

Or

*b)*    *One more effort and we will rest!*

If *b)* is right, it seems that there is a non-verbal expression in *a)* before the comma, and, therefore, perhaps should not be a comma in order to integrate *“One more effort”* in the second clause.

However, the comma was correct before reducing the parts of the sentence that were in brackets.

I will appreciate your clarification about whether *a)* and *b)* are grammatical and idiomatic or not.

Comment: When reducing like that it’s also common to contract:  *we’ll*

Comment: You could also say "One more effort and rest" or "One more effort and then rest". There are a lot of rules on comma usage, and differences of opinion about many of them, but the shorter the sentence the less likely you are to need a comma. A comma or ellipsis might be used to indicate a pause after "one more effort" in speech.